How to move the search icon in the search bar to the left in the Shopware 6 theme?
I'm trying to move the search icon in the search bar to the left in the Shopware 6 theme.
The search icon is currently the most right element in a row of icons.
Here's the relevant SCSS code for the search icon:
.header-search-btn, .header-search-icon, .icon-custom-icons-Search {
    order: -4;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

It doesn't seem to have the desired effect.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Below is a code snippet demonstrating the placement of the search icon in the search bar from the right side to the left side:
.header-search {
    .header-search-input {
        border-right: 1px solid $sw-border-color;
        border-left: 0;
        order: 2;
    }

    .header-search-btn {
        border: 1px solid $sw-border-color;
        border-right: 0;
        margin-left: 0 !important;
    }
}

The result is displayed in the screenshot.
